# Showing all the users who have set their country same as request.user

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to show all the users which set their `Countries` similar to `request.user`.

> For Example : If `user_1` is `request.user` and selected state choice `Victoria` and country `Australia` and then `user_2` registered and set the same state `Victoria` and country `Australia`.

So i want to show all the users that have set their `Country` and `state` same to `request.user` BUT When i access these types of users then It is just showing all users of `same country` BUT it is not showing of `same state`.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def show_user(request.user):
    show = Profile.objects.filter(country=request.user.profile)
    show_state = Profile.objects.filter(state=request.user.profile)

    context = {'show':show,'show_state':show_state}
    return render(request, 'show_user.html', context)
```

When i try to access **{{ show }}** in template then it shows two user have set their country same to `request.user`
BUT
When i try to access **{{ show_state }}** in template it shows nothing.

I have no idea, what am i doing wrong in accessing.
Any help would be Appreciated.
Thank You in Advance.

> Note :- I am using external library to show country and state choices in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a `filter` problem.

```py
request.user.profile # Profile Object

# you're filtering by matching country with request.user.profile
Profile.objects.filter(country=request.user.profile)

# Similar for state
Profile.objects.filter(state=request.user.profile)
```

What you want to do is `filter` using `request.user.profile.state` and `request.user.profile.country`.

```py
# Since this is a view
# Method parameter should be request instead of request.user
def show_user(request):
    show = Profile.objects.filter(country=request.user.profile.country)
    show_state = Profile.objects.filter(state=request.user.profile.state)

    context = {'show':show,'show_state':show_state}
    return render(request, 'show_user.html', context)
```

While this should solve your current problem.

#### Suggestion

With Django, you can actually filter Profiles with country and state that matches user's in the same query.

```py
def show_user(request):
    user_profile = request.user.profile

    valid_profiles = Profile.objects.filter(country=user_profile.country, state=user_profile.state)

    context = {'valid_profiles': valid_profiles}
    return render(request, 'show_user.html', context)
```

Comment: It Worked, Thank You Very Much. AND also Thank you very much for the `Suggestion`